# Does DataFrame.index.empty imply DataFrame.empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a DataFrame, `df`, for which `df.index.empy` is `True`, will this ALWAYS imply that `df.empty` is also `True`?

My intend is to test only df.index.empy when I need to test both conditions (lazy programming style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if one of the columns or index is empty, then the shape of your DataFrame is `(0, x)` or `(x, 0)` and there is necessarily no data in it, so `df.empty` will be `True`.

This is explained in the documentation for [`DataFrame.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html):

> *property* DataFrame.empty
>
> Indicator whether Series/DataFrame is empty.
>
> True if Series/DataFrame is entirely empty (no items), meaning any of the axes are of length 0.

Yet, the reciprocal is not true, a DataFrame can be empty but either the index or columns can be non empty.

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])

df.shape
# (0, 2)

df.empty
# True

df.index.empty
# True

df.columns.empty
# False
```

##### Summary

- if `df.index.empty or df.columns.empty`, then `df.empty` is necessarily `True`
- if `df.empty`, then either of `df.index.empty` or `df.columns.empty` is `True` (or both)

Answer (score 0):

yes, if index of DataFrame is empty it will always satisfies condition of DataFrame.empty

For e.g

> DataFrame.empty = True

works in both condition for index as well as for columns.

Hence if you want to check any of these are empty then you can go with

> DataFrame.empty

else need to be specific

> DataFrame.index.empty